# How to handle concurrency in Propel?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, propel

I'm new to the world of web & databases, and what I don't understand is how usually web application programmers synchronize database information when using ORM.

Let's say that we have this code:

```
$q = new AuthorQuery();
$firstAuthor = $q->findPK(1);

//Now someone changes the value of "LastViewedBy" in database, 
but our PHP code still thinks that the value is "Me"

if( $q->getLastViewedBy() === "Me" )
{
    //Do some stuff...
    //Change information that affect the flow of this method

    $q->save();
}
```

It's a classic synchronization problem (let's say that 10,000 people are executing this script at the same time).

How do I solve it when using Propel and MySQL (InnoDB)?

Comment: Databases handle concurrency. Propel is just an abstraction of lower level database access baked into php. To learn more read about your database of choice. In your case things like: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-create-index-concurrency.html

Comment: @MarkFox Yea I know ACID, etc... but what if you make like if( $obj->getField() ) , but that value we have in our PHP object isn't updated (Because someone else has changed it in the database)

Comment: Right your question is about SQL, not Propel. The spirit of your question is good, but it's more like: how does MySQL queue commands and protect data integrity during large loads? There may already be a canonical answer on S.O. or http://dba.stackexchange.com/ … as a rule though you can assume first-in-first-out execution; near simultaneous access of 10,000 users is more problematic for network routers and the memory limits of your app including the database. If the db has the proper amount of memory it can handle pretty hefty queue size.